# X-axis label at start/end of chart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, axis-labels

I have created a temperature plot in Python using matplotlib and pyplot but cannot figure out how to add a date label for the very first value on the x-axis and the very last label. I have tried multiple iterations of DayLocator, but to no avail. I would like to keep the bounds of the actual plot the same and would like to keep the minor ticks for each day as is in the plot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwN9D.png), so there is not empty space at the beginning or end of the line plot. The data is from 06/01 to 08/30. Here is my full code, which plots perfectly except the very first tick for 06/01 and the very last tick for 08/30 do not show up:

```
import csv
import pylab
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

filename ='Summer17.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   header_row = next(reader)

dates_list, temperature, dewpoint = [], [], []
for row in reader:
    if len(row) < 4: 
        continue
    datestring = ("2017/{0:}/{1:} {2:}".format(*row))
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
    dates_list.append(date_obj) 
    temp = float(row[3])
    temperature.append(temp)




fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.75])
plt.plot(dates_list,temperature, linewidth=0.5, c='red')
plt.xlim(dates_list[1],dates_list[-1])

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d') 
months = mdates.MonthLocator() 
days1 = mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=(1,15))   # every Day
dayss = mdates.DayLocator()

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days1)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dayss)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `2017-06-01` is actually part of the list to plot, it will be shown. `DayLocator(bymonthday=(1,15))` sets ticks for every first and fifteenth of every month and `2017-06-01` is the first of a month, hence it will be shown. (If it isn't, `2017-06-01` is not part of the list.)

The problem may now be that the `2017-08-30` may be part of the list, but it is not the 1st of 15th of any month. So the idea can be to use the `DayLocator(bymonthday=(1,15))` to find the ticks to display but before showing them add the additionally required `2017-08-30` to the list of locations and use a `FixedLocator` instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker
import datetime
import numpy as np

start = datetime.datetime(2017,6,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,8,30)
dates_list = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]

temperature = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(dates_list)))

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d') 
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  
days = mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=(1,15))   
dayss = mdates.DayLocator()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(dates_list,temperature, linewidth=0.5, c='red')

ax.set_xlim(dates_list[0],dates_list[-1])

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dayss)

# add the (2017,8,30) to the ticks
locs = list(ax.get_xticks())+ [mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2017,8,30))]
locator= matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(locs)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My data is in CSV with seperate columns for month, date, and HH:MM. I think my problem was that the first date point was 6 1 00:10. I added a column to the top of the list with 6 1 00:00. This still didnt work. So I added another column to the top with 5 31 23:59 and now it displays that 6/01 value I had been wanting. Could you possibly explain to me why this is the case that it is happening this way? Thanks

Comment: I do understand that using `6 1 00:10` will not result in  `6 1` being displayed, because it is simply 10 minutes past midnight (hence after midnight) and hence `6 1` is not part of the graph. You can test by using `datetime.datetime(2017,6,1,0,1,0)` in the above code. However, `6 1 00:00` being part of the data, it should work. Alternatively you may of course use `ax.set_xlim(datetime.datetime(2017,6,1),datetime.datetime(2017,8,30))`, independently of the actual data, to make sure the limits of the plot are such that the dates to be marked are included in the graph.